# What does 'he' refer in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1024648/synopsis)

> The head of embassy security attempts to go outside and reason with
>   the militants, but he's immediately captured and taken hostage.

it says he's immediately captured and taken hostage, so he means who?

Comment: Could you explain a bit why you are unsure?

Answer (score 2):

"He" here is referring to the "head of embassy security". When pronoun is used in an independent clause after a coordinating conjunction, the chances are that the antecedent of the independent clause lies in the previous clause, as in this sentence:

> John was frightened by his deeds, so he (John) ran away.

Answer (score 2):

Like @quetchalcoatle said, "he" is referring to "the head of embassy security".

Besides all the confusing linguistics lingo, a hint is that there are only two possible people in this sentence that it could refer to: "the head of embassy security" and the "militants". "He" will always refer to a singular person, so we know it's "the head of embassy security" because "the militants" are plural, not singular.